# access property in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, properties, typeerror

```
sorted = Object.keys(PLAYER_LIST).sort(function(a,b){return a.score - b.score}); // have key value
console.log(PLAYER_LIST[sorted[0]].team); // result:"A"

for(var loop=0; loop<=sorted.length; loop++) {
    if(PLAYER_LIST[sorted[loop]].team == "A") { // error
           some code...
    }
  }
```

When I sorting like this. console.log working well. But if sentence is not working. I receive error message. I don't know why. please help me.

```
if(PLAYER_LIST[sorted[loop]].team == "A") {
                            ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'team' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop goes one step too far

```
for (var loop = 0; loop <= sorted.length; loop++) {
//                      ^^ here
```

An arrays length starts at zero when it's empty, and is `1` if the array contains one item.

If you have an array

```
var array = ['a']
```

arrays are zero based, so the first and only item is `array[0]`, and the length is `1`

When you iterate and you go all the way to the arrays length, you go one index too much, and you end up trying to get `array[1]`, which doesn't exist.

What you wanted was

```
for (var loop = 0; loop < sorted.length; loop++) {...
```

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: my terrible mistake..:(